# Programmatically Adding ImageViews to RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating a 2 column list of images in the form of ImageViews, contained in a RelativeLayout.
Here is a diagram of what it looks like:

[image: img]

The RelativeLayout has been created from an XML file with an id of "@id/cardList";

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardListScroll"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cardList">
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The **ImageView**s however are being created within a java class and should continue to be created until there are no more Images in my TypedArray as set in the **while** loop.

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.cardImages);
    RelativeLayout cardList = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardList);

    int counter = 1;
    int length = images.length();
    ImageView[] cards = new ImageView[3];

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cardAParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(215, 215);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cardBParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(215,215);

    while (counter < length) {
        cards[counter] = new ImageView(this);
        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            cardAParams.setMargins(0,((counter-1)/2)*225,0,0);
            cards[counter].setLayoutParams(cardAParams);
            cards[counter].setImageResource(images.getResourceId(counter-1, 0));
            cardList.addView(cards[counter]);
            Toast.makeText(Create.this, ""+counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            counter++;
        } else {
            cardBParams.setMargins(225,((counter-2)/2)*225,0,0);
            cards[counter].setLayoutParams(cardBParams);
            cards[counter].setImageResource(images.getResourceId(counter-1, 0));
            cardList.addView(cards[counter]);
            Toast.makeText(Create.this, ""+counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            counter++;
        }
    }
    images.recycle();
```

I have been able to successfully create two of the images within the list, however no more than that, meaning I can only create one row, when I want multiple. (I tested this by change "while(counter < 3){" to "while(counter <= 3)".

My presumption is that each new **ImageView** in the *cards[]* array will need a corresponding **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams**. I experimented in creating an array of *RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cardsParams[]* however was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Looks like you want a GridView Adapter, not a ScrollView+RelativeLayout.

Comment: Why don't you use a RecylcerView?

Comment: Thanks guys will look into those options! c: